# Unable to login using JDBC Realm on JSF 2 + Glassfish 3

Tags: jsf-2, forms-authentication, glassfish-3

I'm trying to add authentication to a JSF 2 based application. I started up by following [this](http://jugojava.blogspot.com/2011/02/jdbc-security-realm-with-glassfish-and.html) tutorial.

Here are exports from my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `authentication_groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `authentication_groups` VALUES (1,'Guest','Anonymous user','2012-07-18 13:54:34'),(2,'Member','Standart user','2012-07-18 13:54:34'),(3,'Admin','Administrator','2012-07-18 13:54:34');

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (1,'admin','8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918','Samuil','Yanovski','2012-07-24 06:41:56');

CREATE TABLE `users_authentication_groups_link` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `authentication_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `uag_link_users_fk` (`user_id`),
  KEY `uag_link_authentication_groups_fk` (`authentication_group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `uag_link_authentication_groups_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`authentication_group_id`) REFERENCES `authentication_groups` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `uag_link_users_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `users_authentication_groups_link` VALUES (1,1,3,'2012-07-24 06:42:25');

SELECT `u`.`username` AS `username`,
       `u`.`password` AS `password`,
       `g`.`name`     AS `name`
FROM   ( (`observer`.`users_authentication_groups_link` `ug`
          JOIN `observer`.`users` `u`
            ON(( `u`.`id` = `ug`.`user_id` )))
         JOIN `observer`.`authentication_groups` `g`
           ON(( `g`.`id` = `ug`.`authentication_group_id` )));
```

I have one user with username "admin" and password "admin" (encrypted with SHA-256 and Hex encoding).

I have created a JDBC Connection Pool in my Glassfish Admin Console and it is pinging successfully the database. I've assigned this pool to a JDBC Resource named "jdbc/observer". After that in the **Configuration -> server-config -> Security -> Realms** I created "ObserverRealm" with this configuration:

[image]

Here is my **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>jdbcRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/faces/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/private/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>Admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

and **glassfish-web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    <principal-name>Admin</principal-name>
    <group-name>Admin</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

The **login.xml** is pretty basic:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="/templates/master.xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <p>Login to access secure pages:</p>  
        <h:messages />  
        <h:form id="loginForm">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />  
                <h:inputText id="username" value="#{authBackingBean.username}" />  

                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />  
                <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{authBackingBean.password}" />  

                <h:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" action="#{authBackingBean.login}" />  
            </h:panelGrid>  
        </h:form> 
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

and the **AuthBackingBean**:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package yanovski.observer.jsf;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

/**
 *
 * @author Intuitiv-06
 */
@ManagedBean(name = "authBackingBean")
@RequestScoped
public class AuthBackingBean {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AuthBackingBean.class.getName());
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String login() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

        try {
            request.login(username, password);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Login failed!", null));
            return "login";
        }

        //you can fetch user from database for authenticated principal and do some action  
        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        log.info("Authenticated user: " + principal.getName());


        if (request.isUserInRole("Admin")) {
            return "/admins/admins?faces-redirect=true";
        } else {
            return "/users/users?faces-redirect=true";
        }
    }

    public String logout() {
        String result = "/index?faces-redirect=true";

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

        try {
            request.logout();
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to logout user!", e);
            result = "/loginError?faces-redirect=true";
        }

        return result;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong since I always receive "login failed" error when I try to authenticate - using admin/admin for username/password. Please tell me if you need any other details - I could also provide an archive of the project if anyone wants to give it a look.

Thank you in advance and sorry for the long post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have experienced similar issue on our Lubuntu server with Glassfish v3 and PostgreSQL database. Make sure you have installed PostgreSQL driver in your Glassfish domain.

copy to:

> \glassfish\domains\YOURDOMAIN\lib

a JDBC 4 driver which you can find here:

http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Must help :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and sorry for the late response. I'm using MySQL instead of PostgreSQL, so I'll try to migrate the database and give you feedback if it helps. :)

Comment: I guess for mysql there is a similar driver to download :)